# SUSE EC2 Problem - zypper - Permission denied

Tags: amazon-ec2, opensuse, gcc

I'm trying to use zypper to install gcc on my Amazon EC2 instance running SUSE.
When I try:`zypper in gcc`
I get:

`Retrieving repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP1' metadata []
Permission to access 'http://eu-west-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/install/SLE11-SDK-SP1/sle-11-i586/media.1/media' denied.`

`Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/?] (a): i
Retrieving repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP1' metadata [error]
Repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP1' is invalid.
Can't provide /media.1/media : User-requested skipping of a file
Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Warning: Disabling repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP1' because of the above error.
Retrieving repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP1-Updates' metadata [|]
Permission to access 'http://eu-west-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/update/SLE11-SDK-SP1-Updates/sle-11-i586/repodata/repomd.xml' denied.`

`Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/?] (a): i
Retrieving repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP1-Updates' metadata [error]
Repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP1-Updates' is invalid.
Can't provide /repodata/repomd.xml : User-requested skipping of a file
Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Warning: Disabling repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP1-Updates' because of the above error.
Retrieving repository 'SLES11-Extras' metadata [/]
Permission to access 'http://eu-west-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/update/SLES11-Extras/sle-11-i586/repodata/repomd.xml' denied.`

`Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/?] (a): r
Permission to access 'http://eu-west-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/update/SLES11-Extras/sle-11-i586/repodata/repomd.xml' denied.`

`Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/?] (a): zypper in gcc
Invalid answer 'zypper in gcc'. [a/r/i/?] (a): a
Retrieving repository 'SLES11-Extras' metadata [error]
Repository 'SLES11-Extras' is invalid.
Can't provide /repodata/repomd.xml :
Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Warning: Disabling repository 'SLES11-Extras' because of the above error.
Retrieving repository 'SLES11-SP1' metadata [-]
Permission to access 'http://eu-west-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/install/SLES11-SP1/sle-11-i586/media.1/media' denied.`

`Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/?] (a): a
Retrieving repository 'SLES11-SP1' metadata [error]
Repository 'SLES11-SP1' is invalid.
Can't provide /media.1/media :
Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid repository.
Warning: Disabling repository 'SLES11-SP1' because of the above error.
Retrieving repository 'SLES11-SP1-Updates' metadata []
Permission to access 'http://eu-west-1-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/update/SLES11-SP1-Updates/sle-11-i586/repodata/repomd.xml' denied.`

I've search for the problem and [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=202419&tstart=0) came up, but offered no solutions.
I've tried`sces-activate`. Am I doing something wrong?

I should say I'm very new to this, and I admit I don't really know what I'm doing, but I'm trying to learn about setting up and running a server and so I thought I'd throw myself in at the deep(ish) end.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem best directed to Amazon support.

Answer (score 1):

That usually means that the URL or media is not accessible anymore (it is sort of like a 404 message with Debian apt-get or Red Hat's yum). From what I gather, it is supposed to pull the packages from Amazon's SuSE's repos, but now those repos are down. You'll probably need to post a message on Amazon's forums to get Amazon to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all familiar with zypper as a package manager, tho I have used suse v8 and 9.
the Big Gui SUSE tool is YasT (not sure on caps).

I am seeing the same thing in other AWS support threads,like so:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=53398

so maybe its not you.

I've had very easy success on Ec2 using Centos based AMIs and using yum/rpm and also
source compiles.

You should not need to install gcc on a new Ec2 instance,that might be going a bit far
into building from scratch.

I generally feel pretty distro agnostic, and don't have a problem switching between
debian/ubuntu based types and rpm/yum based types.